# ¿Como validar Select con propiedades Required y Disabled a la vez?

Tags: javascript, html, select, required

Explico la pregunta.

En un formulario tengo un Select el cuál inicialmente debe estar deshabilitado, y con un Input-Radio se habilita/deshabilita.

Al habilitar es necesario que sea Requerido ya que debo enviar sus datos al servidor. Pero al enviar el formulario lo envía con datos o sin datos, es decir, la parte del required no lo toma, de alguna manera podría ser porque está disabled al inicio? Necesito que al estar habilitado el formulario lo requiera antes de enviar los datos.

Ahora bien en el html lo tengo requerido y deshabilitado:

```html
<select name="cajaM" id="cajaM" class="form-control" onchange="selcajam()" disabled="disabled" required="required" ></select>
```

La función selcajam() carga los options desde la bd

El Usuario puede habilitarlo el select con los input-radio y seleccionar una opción. Pero si no selecciona nada el formulario se envía normal.

Estos son los input radio

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input class="btn" type="radio" checked="checked" id="optNo" name="selCajaM" value="no" onclick="actCajaM()">
    <label>No</label>  
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input class="btn" type="radio" id="optSi" name="selCajaM" value="si" onclick="actCajaM()">
    <label>Si</label>
</div>
```

Y aquí la función para habilitar/deshabilitar el select:

```
function actCajaM(){
if (document.form_pdm.selCajaM[0].checked){
  document.form_pdm.cajaM.disabled=true;
  document.form_pdm.cajaM.selectedIndex = "";
  sincaja();
}
if (document.form_pdm.selCajaM[1].checked){
  document.form_pdm.cajaM.disabled=false;
  
}
```

}

Así trabaja normal, se guardan los datos sin caja marina.
[image: De esta manera, todo normal, el formulario guarda los datos sin incluir la caja marina]

Así necesito que sea requerido el dato de la caja marina, pero el formulario se envía sin solicitar el dato. Debe advertir que necesito seleccionar alguna opción.
[image: Guarda sin solicitar los datos]

Quiero que cuando esté habilitado el control, pida seleccionar una opción.

Alguna idea para que funcione de esa manera??

El archivo php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['motorid'])){
    require_once('../class/connects.php');
    $id_motor = $_POST['idmotor'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bd_cajam ORDER BY id ASC";
    if($result = $db->query($query)){
        $html="<option value=''>Seleccione</option>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row['id_engine'] == $id_motor){
                $html.="<option value='".$row['id']."'selected>".$row['modelo']."</option>";
            } else {
                $html.="<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['modelo']."</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    $result->free();
    $db->close;
    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// 0  = false
// 1  = true
const select= document.querySelector("select[name='cars']");
function actCajaM(e){
  // e es elemento que se clickeo
  if(e.value == "no"){
     // desabilitamos el input
     select.disabled = 1;
  }else{
    // habilitamos
    select.disabled = 0;
    // agregamos un required 
    select.required = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input class="btn" type="radio" checked="checked" id="optNo" name="selCajaM" value="no" onclick="actCajaM(this)">
            <label>No</label>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input class="btn" type="radio" id="optSi" name="selCajaM" value="si" onclick="actCajaM(this)">
            <label>Si</label>
            
            <div class="col-sm-1">
            <select name="cars" id="cars" disabled>
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola @Bryro gracias por tu respuesta, pero necesito tener un Select, ya que se cargan varias opciones de caja marina desde la BD. Me has colocado un Input en la respuesta.

Comment: solo agregar el options sin value ya corregido!

Comment: Gracias @Bryro, eso me ha funcionado, le he puesto al archivo php donde se cargan las opciones, en el primer option el value vacío. He editado la pregunta y coloque lo que tiene el php.